# How to play animation each time i click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I just can play the animation once, and I want to play it every time when I click on it.
I'm doing a game like dinosaur of google.
The animation is on paused, and the onClick function from JavaScript does put it on the play.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("macaco");

function saltar() {
  document.getElementById("macaco").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  document.getElementById("macaco").style.AnimationPlayState = "running";
}
```

```css
#macaco {
  background-color     : orange;
  height               : 70px;
  width                : 40px;
  transform            : translateX(15vw);
  position             : absolute;
  bottom               : 22px;
  position             : absolute;
  animation            : linear saltar 1s infinite;
  animation-play-state : paused;
  }
@keyframes saltar {
    0% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
   50% { transform: translatey(-120px) translateX(15vw) }
  100% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="saltar()" id="macaco" class="macaco"></div> <!-- Macaco -->
```

I tried with adding an event at the end, but don't know how to us the property because I barely read it. Read about toggle, but also don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const el_macaco = document.getElementById("macaco");

el_macaco.addEventListener('click', saltar);

function saltar()
  {
  el_macaco.classList.toggle('doRun');
  }
```

```css
#macaco {
  position             : absolute;
  bottom               : 22px;
  width                : 40px;
  height               : 70px;
  background-color     : orange;
  transform            : translateX(15vw);
  animation            : linear saltar 1s infinite;
  animation-play-state : paused;
  }
#macaco.doRun {
  animation-play-state : running;
  }
@keyframes saltar {
   0% { transform: translatey(   0px) translateX(15vw) }
  50% { transform: translatey(-120px) translateX(15vw) }
 100% { transform: translatey(   0px) translateX(15vw) }
 }
```

```html
<div id="macaco"></div>
```

Comment: But it still dont work, the animation stays infitinite

Comment: @Janner no it is not infinite, it is just hard to click on it when it move.... it's seems you didn't read my post...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `infinite` (you only want to run it once).  And you have to reset your animation once you have started it so that it can kick off again:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("macaco");

document.addEventListener('animationend', (ev) => {

});

function saltar() {
  var ev = document.getElementById("macaco")
  ev.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  ev.style.AnimationPlayState = "running";
  ev.classList.remove("macaco")
  ev.offsetWidth
  ev.classList.add("macaco")
}
```

```css
.macaco {
  background-color     : orange;
  height               : 70px;
  width                : 40px;
  transform            : translateX(15vw);
  position             : absolute;
  bottom               : 22px;
  position             : absolute;
  animation            : linear saltar 1s 1;
  animation-play-state : paused;
  }
@keyframes saltar {
    0% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
   50% { transform: translatey(-120px) translateX(15vw) }
  100% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="saltar()" id="macaco" class="macaco"></div> <!-- Macaco -->
```

Comment: Thanks!, now it works!
I find also the solution by making it run with a class, and adding this to the js
var macaco = document.getElementById("macaco") ;

 function saltar(){
  macaco.classList.add("play");
  setTimeout(function(){
   macaco.classList.remove("play");
  },1000);
}

Comment: Using an arbitrary timeout is generally a bad idea as it means you will have to remeasure and edit your timeout if your animation changes (or if you add a new animation by copying and pasting code you have).  That being said, if you don't think your animation will ever change then it is fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("macaco");

function removeClass() {
  x.classList.remove('run');
}

function saltar() {
  x.classList.add('run');
  setTimeout(removeClass,1000) //time should match with animation duration
}
```

```css
#macaco {
  background-color     : orange;
  height               : 70px;
  width                : 40px;
  transform            : translateX(15vw);
  position             : absolute;
  bottom               : 22px;
  position             : absolute;
 }
 .run {
  animation: linear saltar 1s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation: linear saltar 1s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
 }
@keyframes saltar {
    0% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
   50% { transform: translatey(-120px) translateX(15vw) }
  100% { transform: translatey(0px) translateX(15vw)    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="saltar()" id="macaco"></div> <!-- Macaco -->
```